# How to include X-XSRF-TOKEN header in Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, csrf, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that I want to add XSRF protection to.  So I now require an antiforgery token in an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` HTTP header on all of my endpoints as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0#javascript-ajax-and-spas).  JavaScript clients get a token by hitting the `/antiforgerytoken` endpoint, which sets an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie containing the token.  This all works fine, but as one would expect, the "Try it out!" feature in Swagger UI no longer works since the requests are missing the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` HTTP header.  Is there a way to have SwaggerUI automatically call the `/antiforgerytoken` endpoint and include the token in the request being executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Swagger UI, this can be supported by setting a `requestInterceptor` on the configuration which is a function that intercepts and modifies outgoing requests, including "Try it out" requests. See [this comment](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2896#issuecomment-339419561) in Swagger UI repo and the [README](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#network) on Swagger UI configuration.

However, `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI` does not yet support setting `requestInterceptor` in C# as of the latest stable release (5.6.3). There is [this PR](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/1809) that added support for interceptors, and it has been merged but not yet released. So if you are using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI`, your options for now is to wait for the next release, or build from source a local version before the next official release.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is this something different from `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIOptions.InjectJavascript()`?

Comment: `InjectJavascript()` does what it says on the tin - it injects the Javascript into the Swagger UI `index.html`. The upcoming changes in the PR however will provide additional config APIs on `SwaggerUIOptions` (`SwaggerUIOptions.Interceptors.RequestInterceptorFunction`) that will directly set `requestInterceptor` on the config object. Ultimately they both modify the Javascript in `index.html`, but for different purposes.